# Racket: How do you use the value of an argument as a symbol?

Tags: racket

I'm new to Racket, and am struggling to find the right words to explain what I'm trying to do. The best I can come up with is this: How do I use the **value** of an argument as a symbol, without calling the function which has the same name as the value of the argument, and without just quoting the **name** of the argument?

Here is a minimal example to show this.

There is a function called `ul` which does something.

There is another function called `make-list` which has a single parameter, `list-type`.

There is a third function, `make-ul`, which calls `make-list` with an argument `ul`.

In the true branch, the function `ul` is applied. Good so far.

In the false branch, I want to be able to use the value of the argument, which in this case is `'ul`, as a symbol. In effect, this line of code would run `(λ args (list* 'ul args))`. How do I achieve this?

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (ul . xs) `(div ,@xs))

(define (make-list list-type)
  (if (equal? 'something 'something-else)
    (λ args (apply list-type args)) ; true branch: call the function "ul"
    (λ args (list* list-type args)))) ; false branch: how to use `ul without calling the "ul" function?

(define make-ul (make-list ul))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to write good Racket code, then the best answer is don't.
Add a separate argument to take the symbol, like this:

```
;; make-list : Procedure Symbol -> Any ... -> Any
(define (make-list proc tag-sym)
  (if ....
      proc ;; (λ args (apply proc args)) simplifies to just proc
      (λ args (list* tag-sym args))))

(define make-ul (make-list ul 'ul))
```

Or if the branch is independent of `args`, you could just have a single argument of type `(U Procedure Symbol)` instead:

```
;; make-list : (U Procedure Symbol) -> Any ... -> Any
(define (make-list list-type)
  (cond [(procedure? list-type)
         ;; (λ args (apply list-type args))
         list-type]
        [(symbol? list-type)
         (λ args (list* list-type args))]))

(define make-ul (make-list ul))
(define make-li (make-list 'li))
```

---

If you want to explore Racket features, there are two main ways to do it.

1. You can make a macro that takes a procedure *name* and uses it both as a reference and quotes it as a symbol. For example, using the first version of `make-list` above:

   ```
   (define-syntax-rule (make-list* proc-name) (make-list proc-name (quote proc-name)))

   (define make-ul (make-list* ul)) ;; => (define make-ul (make-list ul 'ul))
   ```
2. You can call `object-name` on a procedure to ask what Racket thinks its name is. For example, `(object-name list)` returns `'list`, and `(object-name ul)` should return `'ul`. But `(object-name make-ul)` will not return `'make-ul`, because Racket tracks names at compile time, not at run time. (I would advise against writing code that depends on `object-name`; it makes your code very fragile.)

Comment: I’m really grateful for your answer. Not only have you solved the problem, but helped me to think about it from different perspectives. I’ve now read up on macros and can see how they would solve this, but how adding an extra argument would be simplest solution. Thank you again!